# How To Change Device Name Used By Google Chrome Browser For History Tracking

Tags: google-chrome, history, hostname, computer-name

As seen in the image below, this is what Google Chrome thinks the hostname of the Windows 10 machine is. However this is not the case and the hostname is something completely different. How can this be changed?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a Windows PC:

1. You must uninstall Chrome
2. Change the hostname of the PC
3. Reinstall Chrome

*Chrome saves whatever hostname you had when you first installed it, changing the hostname after installing Chrome will not update the hostname in Chrome.*

Answer (score 9):

I found a way to reset the Synced Name under `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Sync Data`

Deleted both the LevelDB folder and Nigori.bin and then turned off Sync in Google Chrome's settings and turn it on again.

Make a backup and check https://chrome.google.com/sync before you do this if you're unsure, this method only contain sync information and would not delete any data like history, bookmarks or settings.

Comment: This worked for me. It appears to me that with a fresh Windows install, if I change the host name *and reboot* before installing Chrome, the host name is applied; if I'm too impatient and get Chrome first, the sync name will be whatever is randomly generated by Windows.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not mistaken, you can edit the device names [here](https://play.google.com/settings) and it *should* reflect globally across all your Google services as long as you have sync settings enabled.

For other devices such as non-Android mobile devices — e.g., iOS — you should be able to edit the device name under `Settings > General > About`.

For desktop — e.g., Windows PC — the device name should match your PC name, which is set in `System Properties`.  NOTE: refer to @Pie’s answer regarding order of significance .

EDIT: Based upon several of the other updated answers, it stands to reason you should be able to navigate to `chrome://sync-internals` and either invoke `Trigger GetUpdates` or — if necessary — toggle `Disable Sync` then re-enable.

Comment: Yes I agree for the Windows PC it should match the hostname of the PC, however it shows as the generic random generated hostname as shown above. This should be editable somewhere.

Comment: `Trigger GetUpdates` did it for me!

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS 12.5.1 and Google Chrome 104.0.5112.101 (arm64), there is no need to uninstall Chrome or manually delete any files.

After disabling and re-enabling sync in Chrome, the new hostname is shown correctly in Chrome History - Tabs from other devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the host name of devices here: https://remotedesktop.google.com/access

Comment: This will only change the computer name shown in the Google remote access service.  I installed Google remote access on my computer and tried then renaming the computer using the specified page but the computer name shown in the browser-sync hasn't changed.